# Git - list of commits, but get only last commit of the day

Tags: git, git-log

I want to create really simple statistics from my code. I use `git rev-list` to obtain list of all commits back to history. But for my purposes only the last commit of the day is interesting. I want to omit all commits that precedes that commit during any particular day.
Given the history:

```
c1375e3 Nov 13 07:55:31
110d2ec Nov 13 07:41:47
30331dd Nov 12 21:23:47
431addf Nov 12 18:50:52
8a32d78 Nov 12 18:27:24
ace5a88 Nov 12 18:24:55
```

I'm interested only in commits `30331dd` and `c1375e3`. How I can get list like that?

Comment: It is trivial with a few lines of ruby (or, say, python).

Comment: What arguments do yo pass to `git rev_list` to get this list of commits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pipe the output of the `git rev-list` command you use into awk:

```
git rev-list your_command | awk '{if(m!=$2 || d!=$3){m=$2;d=$3; print $1}}'
```

Of course, it will work only if the list of commits is ordered by date and time, as shown in your example.